# How can I sort rows in Excel alphabetically, without including all columns in the sort?

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

Trying to sort data in Excel alphabetically by row, but NOT in all of the columns for each row.

For example:
Sort J7 through U7 alphabetically, then J8 through U8, all the way down through J2000 through U2000, while keeping each item within its row (like all cells in row 7 should still be in row 7 by the end of it.)

It seems like I'll need to use a macro/VBA for this, as Excel only lets you sort one row at a time alphabetically. If I select more than one row to sort, it still only sorts the first row.

I have done a bit of research as far as what kind of macros I could use for this, but nothing seems to do the job. The one thing I found that was similar to this sorts by number, but can't sort alphabetically.

Here's what I've got at a moment. I recorded a macro of myself selecting and sorting the row so that I could hopefully get all the code for that right at least:

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+j
'

Dim lngIndex As Long
Dim strArray(9 To 11000) As String
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim x As Integer
intCounter = 1
x = 9
For lngIndex = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
intCounter = intCounter + 1
strArray(lngIndex) = intCounter
x = x + 1
Range("Jx:UNx").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).csv").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).csv").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
Range("Jx:UNx"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).csv").Sort
.SetRange Range("Jx:UNx")
.Header = xlNo
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlLeftToRight
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
Next

End Sub
```

The error I'm getting right now is "Compile Error: Next Without For" for that "Next" at the bottom. But obviously there is a For higher up, and as far as I know they should be linked unless the "With" in between is messing things up. I've tried Next on it's own like it is above, as well as "Next IngIndex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your With block doesn't have an End. Try like this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).csv").Sort
.SetRange Range("Jx:UNx")
.Header = xlNo
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlLeftToRight
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With 'I have added this line to close your With block
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed that part, and now it's telling me this:
Run-time error ‘1004’:
The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it’s within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn’t the same or blank.

And it's highlighting the ".Apply" from right before the End With line.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Now that I've saved it, it's "export_729559 (3).xlsx". So I've updated the code to reflect that and it's cleared the .Apply error.

Now I'm getting:
Run-time error ‘9’:
Subscript out of range

And it's highlighting the line:
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).xlsx").Sort.SortFields.Clear

Comment: @RebeccaHanan, I'd like to help you but here it comes an error after the other and they're pretty simple ;) I suggest you to look for the definition of the errors on Google, you will definitely find some help out there. Here you should just ask for specific questions, not debugging service. If the question is another one now, close this thread by marking the answer and open a new one but try to look for on the web as well! Little tip: "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" comes typically if the sheet doesn't not exist or, in general, if you're looking for an element that is not there.